# How to use loop over multiple events in a single text file?

Tags: python, plot

I am a new beginner in programming. I have multiple events(more than 1000 Number of events) inside the single text file(data.txt). For example

```
BoardID: 31

Channel: 1

Event Number: 3123

Pattern: 0x0000

2627.000000

2627.000000

2626.009033

2629.000000
.
.
.(up to 1024 data)

BoardID: 31

Channel: 1

Event Number: 3124

Pattern: 0x0000

2627.000000

2627.000000

2628.949707

2626.099365
.
.
....(up to 1024 data)
.
..1000 number of events
```

How can I plot all the data one by one by using a loop over the multiple events.

I am trying the following python code but it does not work:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:

for i in range(1000):  #I have 1000 number of events
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    def plot_event(start = 4, all_lines= 'all_lines'):
        lines = all_lines[start : 1029 - 4 + start]

        return (plot_event(4*i, all_lines))

    x = np.array(range(1,1025)) #for all the events x has same range
    y2 = float(lines.split()[0])
    y2_=list(y2)
    y22 = [((j / 4096)-0.5) for j in y2_]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   
ax.set_xlabel('Time (ns)')
ax.set_ylabel('counts')
ax.plot(x,y22, 'k-', color= 'b', label='data') 
fig=plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

Can somebody explain how I can have each event be plotted one by one using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mostly the right code, just some issues with indentation and ordering

You try to read in the entire file 1000x over, except after the first time you have reached the end fo the file and get nothing back

Also the plotting should be within the loop

```
# read in the file. We only need to do this once
with open('data.txt') as f:
    all_lines = [line for line in f]

define x outside of the loop. Numpy has a range generating function. Use that
x = np.arange(1,1025)

# loop through each event
for start in range(1000):
    # get data points
    # each event has values at 1028*start:1028*(start+1), but we don't need the first 4 values
    # defining y2 as an array automatically handles the float conversion
    # also makes the math easier
    y2 = np.array(all_lines[1028*start+4:1028*(start+1)],dtype=float)
    y22 = y2 / 4096 - .5

    # plot stuff. I just copies your code here
    # only change was putting it in the loop
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (ns)')
    ax.set_ylabel('counts')
    ax.plot(x,y22, 'k-', color='b', label='data')
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.show()
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks David L, But when I use     y2 = np.array(all_lines[1029*start+4:1029*(start+1)],dtype=float)  # I got ValueError: could not convert string to float: Pattern: 0x0000.    When I use y2 = np.array(all_lines[1029*start+4:1029*(start)],dtype=float)   # I got the y2 empty.

Comment: got the problem, sorry. I was copying the 1029 number from your code without thinking about it. Changing it to 1028 should fix it IF: your data is of the form 4 labels (BoardID, channel, Event Number, Pattern) followed by 1024 lines of numbers. If the number of digits per event can vary, that would require altering up the code a bit